Vue.js Pinia State and DevExpress Data Grid Issue
I am using Pinia store for state management.
I am maintaining a reactive array named userPositions which takes some time to take up values. So initially it is empty and then upon component mounting, I make some service calls and based upon some calculations I update the userPositions array.
I am using Data Grid to display the content of the array. Now the problem is that the userPositions array takes some time to build and get updated in the pinia store, so the data grid renders first showing "No Data" which is fair enough because the data takes up 1-2 seconds to get updated in the state. The problem is that even after 1-2 seconds, the grid continues to show "No data" even when the userPositions reactive array has been updated in the pinia store.
Why does the grid not re-render again when the value of the datasource was updated?
Also, if i make any change in my code editor and then save the project, the grid starts showing the updated array value.
Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Please share how you are updating the state, how the relevant part of the state looks like and how you're consuming it in the component which doesn't update. Ideally you should present a runnable [mcve] (using codesandbox.io or similar) which would allow others to test any potential solutions, as well as give more insight on relevant package versions used. Where possible, remove the code that's irrelevant for reproducing (and solving) your issue.
